# How to manage large projects without Visual Studio?

Tags: c#, project-management, compilation

How does one go about keeping track of source files, resources, references, assemblies, etc.. if they didn't want to use Visual Studio. I know you can compile code with csc, and use csc to add all of the references, etc.. but it becomes quite painful to add these references as the project grows.

How do you manage it when splitting the project up into separate folders (different modules, etc..) and how do you manage dependencies, build order, etc..

Are there any open source (free) projects for managing this? Even so, is it fairly simple for one to do this without having to download any 3rd party programs?

Comment: You just want to skip on buying Visual Studio? If the price is the problem, you can download a free version that has less features.

If you're a professional then you should buy a license, it's a great IDE.

Comment: Also if you have a business that's less than 3 years old and meet a few other easy conditions, you can get MSDN (including the full Visual Studio) for free, with a $100 "exit" fee once the free period is up. http://www.microsoftstartupzone.com/pages/home.aspx

Comment: No, I don't want to avoid paying for Visual Studio. I actually own a copy. I am just an avid ViM user, and really do not like any of the plugins for vim+visual studio. I wanted to see if I can manage the project I am working on with just vim. I have intellisense setup, I compile and it lists the errors in the same window. I am working on highlighting specific lines. Would like to NOT use .sln and .csproj files.

Comment: I still think you want MSBuild.  Its output is regular/parseable, should be easy to wire up e.g. for compiling, listing errors, etc.  An even .proj files, while not beautiful, are often straightforward to edit/manage 'by hand' with an editor.  And if you get to know MSBuild well, it is quite powerful.  I would not dismiss it too lightly; I would think it would be compatible with your ultimate goals for a Vim-heavy 'IDE'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use [MSBuild](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MSBuild) as well as project and solution files provided you know their format.

Comment: Indeed - MSBuild is "the" solution.  Even if you are using VS, MSBuild is doing all the heavy lifting here.  And MSBuild is part of the .Net Framework, msbuild.exe lives right next to csc.exe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use many of the [Open Source Build Systems for C#](http://csharp-source.net/open-source/build-systems).

Of these, [NAnt](http://nant.sourceforge.net/) is quite popular, especially for people transitioning from Java.

Answer (score 0):

As long as your projects arent complex (referencing lots of assemblies, resource files, etc). You can manage with just an editor and "autogenerated" csproj files. The basic structure of the csproj file is very straightforward, and the same in 80% of the projects, setup a pre-build task to construct the csproj from template and then execute csc.

NAnt I believe has a generic task for "build directory" that would let you do it, but you will have to have some automation to setup the nant scripts initially.

Answer (score 0):

You can actually use makefiles if you're really keen. Some of our early .NET integration into our build system uses makefiles rather than csproj. However it is something of a black art which I have personally never fully understood, i.e. sorry I can't give you any prescriptive advice/samples. Nowadays we just msbuild which is considerably easier.